# There was an error installing Swoole php-cp, how can I fix the problem?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.4, swoole, octane

Have error building of
[swoole/php-cp](https://github.com/swoole/php-cp)

1. Ubuntu 20.04
2. PHP7.4

[How can fix this error?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLwJI.png)

Comment: IN which php frame work you are trying to use this
This https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLwJI.png repo seems to be read only

Comment: @Shibon Laravel/octane

Comment: https://github.com/breeze2/laravel-swoole-cp